# Tagging multiple EC2 instances with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, count, terraform, tags

how can I set different tags for whatever number of instances I'll create? the problem here is the servers will be server-1, server-2, etc.., but what I actually want is to set different values instead of using the value "Server" for all instances.

```
resource "aws_instance" "myapp-server" {
ami           = data.aws_ami.Latest-amazon-linux-image.id
instance_type = var.instance_type
count = "${var.instance_count}"
subnet_id = aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id
vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_default_security_group.default-sg.id]
availability_zone = var.az
associate_public_ip_address = true

tags = {
  Name = "Server-${count.index+1}"
}
}
```

Comment: `Server-${count.index+1}` - you don't have to add `+1`, just have it like: `Name = "Server-${count.index}"`. Besides this, what is your problem more exactly?

Comment: I would advise against managing prod and non-prod servers together like this. Doing it this way will make it difficult to test changes in non-prod before applying to prod.

Comment: I used Server-${count.index+1} because I don't want the count to start from 0, the problem here is the servers will be server-1, server-2, etc.., but what I actually want is to set different values instead of using the value "Server" for all instances

Comment: This should be part of your question.

Comment: What kind of values? Random?

Comment: yes, random values